# CentOS+LUKS: Unlock Multiple Disks @Boot with One Password Prompt

Tags: centos7, luks

In Debian, I am able to unlock multiple disks at bootup with only one prompt, using decrypt_keyctl and the initramfs switch in /etc/crypttab.  I am wondering how to do this in CentOS-7?

A plain vanilla install of Nethserver with two luks devices has a crypttab is similar to this:

```
luks_root   UUID=<uuid1>   none
luks_swap   UUID=<uuid2>   none
```

I'd like to add another disk.  (And, how is it the present bootup happens with only one password prompt, when there are two devices?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that systemd is now capable of unlocking multiple devices with the same password, all at boot time, and will do it with nothing other than what is listed in the crypttab of the OP.  So for more disks, it just takes adding more lines that are similar.  At bootup, if you type the password wrong the first time, then it will ask you for each password individually.